# Get object key using async.each

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have some JSON data as follows:

```
{ 
    version: 1,
    partitions: { 
        '0': [ 1616133379 ], 
        '1': [ 1616133378 ], 
        '2': [ 1616133380 ] 
    } 
}
```

I am looping through the data using async.each as follows:

```
async.each(topicData.partitions, function(data, callback){
    console.log('/brokers/topics/' + topic + '/partitions/' + data + '/state');
    callback();
},
function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    }
});
```

The output I'm getting is:

> '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/1616133379/state'
>   '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/1616133378/state'
>   '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/1616133380/state'

As you can see the `data` item passed through the `async.each` function is holding the value of the key/value pair whereas I actually want it to pass the key to produce this output:

> '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/0/state'
>   '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/1/state'
>   '/brokers/topics/testing/partitions/2/state'

Is there anyway I can get the key passed as opposed to the value?

**This has to be run asynchronously.**

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [async.js each get index in iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516981/async-js-each-get-index-in-iterator)

Comment: Google `async.each key` -> [I Feel Lucky]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`forEachOf`](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachOf), the iterator gets passed the value and key of each item in case of an object.

> iterator(item, key, callback) - A function to apply to each item in obj. The key is the item's key, or index in the case of an array. The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occurred, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.

Usage:

```
async.forEachOf(topicData.partitions, function(item, key, callback){
  console.log('/brokers/topics/' + topic + '/partitions/' + key + '/state');
  callback();
}, function(err){
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect that worked thank you.  I'm new to the async library so hadn't seen that one yet

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your loop.

```
console.log(topicData.partitions.indexOf(data));
```

Comment: That just threw an error                     `console.log(topicData.partitions.indexOf(data));
                                                         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'`